# How can I change this code generator from a list to a string (python)

Tags: python, string

```py
import random
import string
import random
    
letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
print("String as asscii letters:\n", string.ascii_letters)
print("Letter:", letter)    

number = random.randint(1111,9999)
print("Number:" , number)

verification = []
verification.append(number)
verification.append(letter)
print("Verification:", verification)
```

This is just a random code I was making for learning purposes but I want to learn how I can change the list to strings.

Comment: use "str(verrification)"

Comment: `", ".join(verrification)` also works.

Comment: @Ghoti, it will fail because it expect all elements of the list to be `str`, but `nuber` is `int`.

Comment: That depends on what string you want. Let's say `number == 1234` and `letter == 'c'`. What result do you want?

Comment: Fair. Get's more complicated, but list comprehension to convert to string: `", ".join([str(x) for x in verrification])`

Comment: @Ghoti - no need for the inner list - `", ".join(str(x) for x in verrification)` is sufficient. creating a temporary inner list is simply wasteful ;-)

Comment: @Raavgo - that will include the outer [] so might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this. If you want to preserve the brackets, you can use the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) method:

```
my_string = str(verrification)
```

or, using the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
my_string = "[" + ", ".join(str(i) for i in verrification) + "]"
```

If you don't want to keep the brackets:

```
my_string = ", ".join(str(i) for i in verrification)
```

Please note you have to make all items a string in order to use the `join` method. Here, I am using a [`generator expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) to convert all items into a string. This is a very basic problem, so I would suggest searching up a tutorial or looking at a beginner's course to python.

Comment: @buran I fixed my answer

Comment: or `my_string = str(verification)[1:-1]` removes the brackets too.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Nice; let me add that